# Is there a way to use Grok or Regex Match in File Input Plugin

Tags: logstash

I want to ask that is there a way to use grok or regex match in file input plugin in logstash ? And if yes, how ?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Could you explain wich use case need to combine input and filter ? Because with condition a majority part of use case must be fix.

Answer (score 0):

With your limited details, I assume you want to pick up some specific files in your directories, based on some matching patterns. This can be handled in multiple ways:

Exclusions (matched against the filename, not full path).

1. Filename patterns are valid here, too. For example, if you have to just include ".log" files from a directory, you can use:

> input {   file {
> path => "/var/log/applicationDir/*.log"
> }  }

2. In Tail mode, you might want to exclude gzipped files:

> input {   file {
> path => "/var/log/applicationDir/"
> exclude => "*.gz"
> }  }